# Matlab: Speed-up reading of ascii file

Tags: performance, matlab, ascii

I wrote this piece of code which works fine, but is way too slow for my purposes:

```
%%% load nodal data %%% 
path = sprintf('%sfile.dat',directory);
fid = fopen(path);

num_nodes = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %d',1,'delimiter', ' ');
num_nodes = num_nodes{5};
header = textscan(fid,'%s',7,'delimiter', '\t');

k = 0;
while ~feof(fid)

    line        = fgetl(fid);
    [head,rem]  = strtok(line,[' ',char(9)]); 

    if head == '#'
        k = k+1;
        j = 1;
        time_steps(k)  = sscanf(rem, [' Output at t = %d']);        
    end

    if ~isempty(head)
        if head ~= '#'
            data(j,:,k)  = str2num([head rem]); 
            j = j+1;
        end
    end

end
fclose(fid);

nodal_data = struct('header',header,'num_nodes',num_nodes,'time_steps',time_steps,'data',data);
```

The ascii I am reading into Matlab looks something like this:

```
# Number of Nodes: 120453
#X                  Y                   Z                   depth               vel_x               vel_y               wse             
# Output at t = 0
       76456.003              184726             3815.75                   0                   0                   0             3815.75
       76636.003              184726             3728.25                   0                   0                   0             3728.25
       76816.003              184726                3627                   0                   0                   0                3627
       76996.003              184726             3527.75                   0                   0                   0             3527.75
       77176.003              184726              3371.5                   0                   0                   0              3371.5
# Output at t = 36000.788
       76456.003              184726             3815.75                   0                   0                   0             3815.75
       76636.003              184726             3728.25                   0                   0                   0             3728.25
       76816.003              184726                3627                   0                   0                   0                3627
       76996.003              184726             3527.75                   0                   0                   0             3527.75
       77176.003              184726              3371.5                   0                   0                   0              3371.5
```

While the code I wrote works for files very small, it blows up on me for larger ascii files. I already had to abort loading a ~25mb ascii (approximately 240k lines), which was just a test file. Later versions of the file will be ~500mb. Is there a way of speeding up the process of loading the file I am not happy with the 3 if-statements, but I did not know how to seperate '#' from numbers with a switch on head, especially because I was not able to distinguish 'head' by class, i.e. I was trying to check either for ischar or isnumeric, but as the variable 'head' is read as string, it will always be the case of `ischar` and never never `isnumeric` = `true`. I am also not very happy with using a tokenizer at all to being able to use the if-cases and then putting together the line here: `str2num([head rem]);`, as this probably consumes a lot of time. However, I did not know how else to do it.
So if you have any useful suggestions as of how to adapt my code, I would highly appreciate them!

Have a good sunday and thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have an idea of the number of records or their structure? At first glance, I think one of your biggest bottlenecks will be that you constantly reallocate data, as it grows dynamically. You should try to preallocate that.

Comment: Yes, I read the number of nodes into `num_nodes` which is 120453 or 5 in my example case here! I will try to pre-allocate the data, but I do not know the number of time-steps unless I read in the whole file or open it with notepad++, which kills the purpose and isn't fun for 500mb documents!

Comment: And is the number of nodes constant per timestep? If so, you can: read one timestep, count the number of bytes you've read by the time you're finished, estimate the number of timesteps in the file and preallocate that. You might still do reallocations, but they should be few if your estimate is good (and you don't get the O(n^2) running time of reallocating every time).

Comment: Yes, the number of nodes is always constant! So you are suggesting to read until timestep 1 and count the bytes, dividing the total file-size by the number of bytes and setting `time_steps = NaN(total_size/size_step1,7)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below does reads approx 70000 timesteps with 5 nodes per step in around 7 seconds.  It does most of what your code does and it should be easy enough to add the extra features of your code.  There will be other ways of doing this faster but hopefully this should be adequate.

```
filename = 'd:\temp\input.txt';

filetext = fileread(filename);
headerLines = 2;
valuesPerLine = 7;
expr = '[^\n]*[^\n]*';
lines = regexp(filetext, expr, 'match');
isTimeStep = cellfun(@(x) strncmp(x,'#',1), lines );
numTimeSteps = sum(isTimeStep)-headerLines;
nodesPerStep = ((length(lines)-headerLines) / numTimeSteps ) - 1;
data = zeros(nodesPerStep, valuesPerLine, numTimeSteps);

for timeStep = 1:numTimeSteps
    lineIndex = headerLines + (timeStep-1) * (nodesPerStep + 1) + 2;
    for node = 1:nodesPerStep
        data(node, :, timeStep ) = sscanf(lines{lineIndex},'%f');
        lineIndex = lineIndex + 1;
    end    
end
```

Just tried it on a 2 million line file (340000 time steps with 5 nodes per step) and it took approx 36 seconds to run.

If you want a solution that doesn't have coded loops, you could replace from the code from

```
data = zeros(....
```

with

```
values = cellfun(@(x) sscanf(x,'%f'),lines(~isTimeStep),'uniformoutput',false);
data = reshape(cell2mat(values), nodesPerStep, valuesPerLine, numTimeSteps);
```

but it takes about 50% longer to run.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my case. I am excited to see how fast this code is on the large ascii files. Thanks for your solution. Will stick with this and adapt it to my needs!

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do before you change anything is to **PRE-ALLOCATE** all output arrays:
Your code outputs `time_steps` and `data`, all growing inside the loop. This can kill you performance.

*Assuming there are always five lines between each time step*.

Add the following lines before the loop

```
data = reshape( NaN( num_nodes, 7 ), [], 7, 5 ); % assuming 7 columns and 5 lines for each time step
time_steps = NaN( num_nodes / 5 );
```

after the loop just discard remaining NaNs

```
data( isnan(data) ) = [];
time_step( isnan(time_step) ) = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the edit! However, as I told Pablo in my comment above, I do not know the number of time-steps in advance. Therefore, I can only pre-allocate data in the A,B dimension (which is the number of nodes and the number of parameters per node, but the third dimension is the time, i.e., the number of timesteps, which I do not know, unless I read the file or opened it manaully, which is not very convenient, as they are very large. Your first line throws an error btw:

`Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 35, not divisible into
total number of elements, 843171.`

Comment: @TheodorBecker - whatever you decide to do, pre-allocation is CRUCIAL for performance in Matlab. You may read all data into `num_nodes`-by-`num_columns` 2D matrix and only after reading break the matrix according to time steps. BUT YOU MUST PRE-ALLOCATE!

Comment: Alright, I pre-allocated the two output matrices and you were right: the code runs way faster. +1